# Numerical Solution to $ 7000 = \sum_{n=1}^{5} \frac{ \ 1000}{(1 + x)^n} + \sum_{n=6}^{10} \frac{\ 2000}{(1 + x)^n}. $

Tags: numerical-methods

> $$
> 7000 = \sum_{n=1}^{5} \frac{ \ 1000}{(1 + x)^n} + \sum_{n=6}^{10} \frac{\ 2000}{(1 + x)^n}.
> $$

I need to solve the equation above. Since it generates a $10th$ degree polynomial, the equation must be solved by some numerical method. However, I'm unfamiliar with numerical methods, so I need a little hand.

Comment: Can you see why there is at least one solution between say $x=0$ and $x=9$?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: A equation $f(x)=0$ where $f$ is continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ has at least one root in $(a,b)$ if $f(a)f(b)<0$.

Comment: The answers below do not actually explain any numerical methods. You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/309178/272831) for example. To guarantee convergence, bracketing methods can be used. A number of root-finding methods are explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb0Tx2oJWuYIpNE23qYHGQD42TIR3ThNz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y = 1/(1+x)$ the equation can be written as
$$ 2\,{y}^{10}+2\,{y}^{9}+2\,{y}^{8}+2\,{y}^{7}+2\,{y}^{6}+{y}^{5}+{y}^{4
}+{y}^{3}+{y}^{2}+y-7 = 0
$$
(EDIT):
There is one positive real root, approximately $y=0.8772131213$.
The corresponding $x$ value is $1/y - 1 \approx 0.1399738282$.
There is one negative real root, approximately $y=-1.190960306$.
The corresponding $x$ value is $-1.839658547$.

Comment: It may be easier to find a value if one multiplies through by $y-1$ to get $2y^11 - y^6 - 8y + 7 = 0$.  Or it may not.  On the one hand there are less terms; on the other hand $y = 1$ is a root of this polynomial but isn't a root of the polynomial we actually care about.

Comment: Clearly there are two real roots?

Comment: Sorry: one positive real root.

Answer (score 0):

Considering what @Robert Israel did,
$$f(y)=2\,{y}^{10}+2\,{y}^{9}+2\,{y}^{8}+2\,{y}^{7}+2\,{y}^{6}+{y}^{5}+{y}^{4
}+{y}^{3}+{y}^{2}+y-7 = 0$$ it seems to me that there must be two real roots.

By inspection, $f(-2)=1379$, $f(-1)=-6$, $f(0)=-7$, $f(1)=8$. Using Newton method
$$y_1=-1.19096\qquad   y_2=0.877213 \implies x_1=0.139974\qquad   x_2=-1.83966$$

Looking at the original problem in $x$, there is a vertical asymptote at $x=-1$ and then one solution on the left and one on the right of it.